# Can't call scripts inside iframe once src has been changed

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe which loads a simple html:

```
<iframe id="the-frame" name="the-frame" src="/index.html"
 sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-modals" />
```

the src of the iframe which is index.html contains a simple function:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Report Card.css">      
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function printReport() {
            alert('123');
        }       
    </script>
</body>
```

The page hosting this iframe calls this printReport() as needed:

```
function viewReport(useV2) {
    const iframe = document.getElementById("the-frame");
    
    // If this part is uncommented, printReport() is undefined
    // if (useV2)
    //    iframe.src = "/indexv2.html";

    iframe.contentWindow.printReport();

    closePrintOptions();
}
```

As you can see, when this method is called, I get a reference to the contentWindow of the iframe and call the printReport() function. This works except when I try to change the iframe src to another html file, printReport() becomes undefined.

The new src which is indexv2.html is the exact same code as the original one, only difference is it calls alert("456") instead of alert("123"). I've checked the attributes of the iframe in the console window and when using what I originally setted, I can see the printReport() as part of its attributes. But when the src is changed, I don't see it in the console window.

I've also tried using full URL for src but I still can't call the function. I've verified the file is accessible as I can browse indexv2.html via the browser.

Any ideas for this?

Comment: perhaps you need to *wait* for the new page to load in the iframe

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for the reply. It seems it is indeed the case. I will mark it as the answer if you post as an answer,

Comment: you can answer it yourself, you probably know exactly how you coded the solution :p

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by making sure document was loaded before calling anything from the content window.

Thanks to Jaromanda X for giving the idea of the cause of the issue:

```
function viewReport(reportFile) {
    const iframe = document.getElementById("the-frame");
    if (reportFile) {
        iframe.src = reportFile;
        iframe.onload = function () {
            iframe.contentWindow.printReport();
            closePrintOptions();
        }
    }
    else {
        iframe.contentWindow.printReport();
        closePrintOptions();
    }
}
```